# How to override OData filter query validator to allow the properties not defined the model

Tags: odata

I am using Asp.NET OData v7.0 (Microsoft.AspNet.OData). I want to customize the filter validator to allow the properties not defined in my model.

example, my model is defined as this:

```
public Product
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And if I filter on a not defined the property as this:
$filter=Title eq 'abc'

I will get following error:

```
Could not find a property named 'Title' on type 'xx...Models.Product
```

Is it possible to override the FilterQueryValidator to ignore this error?

I tried to override the ValidateSingleValuePropertyAccessNode:

```
public class MyFilterValidator : FilterQueryValidator
{
   public override void Validate(...)
   {
       base.Validate(...);
   }

   public override void ValidateSingleValuePropertyAccessNode(...)
   {
       // my customized code
   }       
}
```

And in my controller:

```
queryOptions.Filter.Validator = new MyFilterValidator(new DefaultQuerySettings());
queryOptions.Filter.Validate(new ODataValidationSettings());
```

But it does not work. When debugging, I saw that Validate(...) is called, but ValidateSingleValuePropertyAccessNode(...) never be called. I also override all of the ValidateXXXX methods, but none of them being called.

Comment: were you able to overcome this issue?